# JMX Event Notifer - Re-register after connection is lost and back up

Tags: asynchronous, notifications, jmx

I have a client that registers with JMX for notifications.
Whenever that JMX Notifications Emitting application is restarted I get an exception

```
01/08/2010 16:28:04 com.sun.jmx.remote.ws.client.JMXWSManStub fetchNotifications
WARNING: Exception java.io.IOException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connectoccured during fetch. Closing connection
```

And stop getting notifications (Obviously).

I would like to be able to catch this exception so I can start a thread that will poll on the target application until it's back up and then I would like to re-register with the events.

My question is - How can I handle this exception myself? Currently the JMX Platform catches it and I'm not sure If I can take over handling it myself.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well.. Since no one answered...

My solution was to do polling on the server by removing and re-adding notifications every few seconds.
It's not perfect but there is really no way (That I could find) to 'ask'  if a notification is  still listening.